# Добавление записи в бд через форму. php

Tags: php, html, база-данных, mysqli

Выводит что информация занесена в бд. Но ее там нету.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где моя ошибка.

```
<form id="form_koment" method="post" action="add.php">
        <p>Имя</p>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <p>Повідомлення</p>
        <textarea cols="70" rows="10" name="text"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="добавить запись"><br>
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text'])){
// Переменные с формы
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

// подключаемся к серверу
$db_host =  "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "batlbot98";
$db_table = "komments";
// Подключение к базе данных
$db = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_table) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");

// Выборка базы
mysqli_select_db("mydb",$db);

// Установка кодировки соединения
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$db);

$result = mysqli_query ("INSERT INTO messages(id,name,text) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$text')");
if ($result = 'true'){
    echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
}else{
    echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `if ($result = 'true')` вместо `if ($result == true)`, при условии, что все остальное вы написали правильно.

Comment: Да, все правильно, теперь выводит что запись не занесена в бд.
Только вот я не понимаю причину.
Дело в этой строке?
$result = mysqli_query ("INSERT INTO messages(id,name,text) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$text')");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Выводит что информация занесена в бд. Но ее там нету. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где моя ошибка.

Отметил, что исправил

```
<form id="form_koment" method="post" action="add.php">
        <p>Имя</p>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <p>Повідомлення</p>
        <textarea cols="70" rows="10" name="text"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="добавить запись"><br>
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text'])){
// Переменные с формы
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

// подключаемся к серверу
$db_host =  "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "batlbot98";
$db_name = "komments"; // 
// Подключение к базе данных

// Подключение к базе данных                              --> or die <--
$db = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name) or die("Не могу создать соединение ");


// Выборка базы
// mysqli_select_db("mydb",$db); //Мне не совсеи ясна эта строка

// Установка кодировки соединения
mysqli_query($db,"SET NAMES 'utf8'"); // $db идёт первым

$result = mysqli_query ($db,"INSERT INTO messages(id,name,text) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$text')"); // $db идёт 
if ($result == true){ // if ($result = 'true') вместо if ($result == true)
    echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
}else{
    echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
}
}
?>
```

---

- [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)  — Выполняет запрос к базе данных

Comment: Добавлю к Вашему ответу, что в момент инициализации переменной `$db`, переменная `$db_name` не объявлена нигде выше.

Comment: @Alexxosipov это была попытка понять что есть `$db_table` =)

Comment: а почему вот так не хотите? if ($result)